# Is Claude-3-Haiku a mixture of experts model?

Tags: large-language-models, claude

If it is not, it is a significant step forward as it is at the level of the original GPT-4, which is a mixture of experts.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this "claude-3-haiku" that describes it?

Comment: @nbro https://www.anthropic.com/news/claude-3-family